# Adding decimal places for glue command in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-glue

Continuation to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73483440/labelling-issues-with-greek-letters-superscript-and-expression-in-facet-wrap/73484008?noredirect=1#comment129770199_73484008).

The labels in `facet_wrap()` contains numbers with different decimal places. I used `glue` R package. The codes and the associated figures are given below.

```
data <- data.frame(N = runif(30, 200, 600),
                   powers = runif(30, 0.03, 0.06),
                   low = runif(30, 0.03, 0.04),
                   upp = runif(30, 0.04, 0.05),
                   q = rep(c(0.02,0.04,0.06,0.08,0.10,0.12), 5))

N = data[,1]
p = data[,2]
q = data[,3]
low = data[,4]
upp = data[,6]
powers = data[,5]

ggplot(data,aes("x" = N, "y" = powers))+
  geom_point() + geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~glue('phi[1]*" = {q}"'), nrow = 2, labeller = label_parsed)+
  labs("y" = "Powers")
```

[image: Figure 1]

How do I make sure that the labels wrote $\phi_1 = 0.10$ instead of $\phi_1 = 0.1$?

Comment: It's hard to know if answers are correct if we cannot reproduce the problem. Can you share part of your data? (or similar data that reproduce the problem?)

Comment: I have added randomly produced data. The plots will be different but it is sufficient.

Comment: Can you check your code again, there is no powers?

Comment: Sorry, I have fixed it. Unfortunately, I can give the data because it is long. Your answer has fixed it, after I tweaked it just tiny bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `format` and `nsmall`:

```r
... +
facet_wrap(~ glue('phi[1]*" = {format(round(q, 2), nsmall = 2)}"') +
...
```

Comment: Unfortunately, both did not work. but I tweaked it. Second method digits = 2, worked.